# sql string split for defined number of char

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, plsqldeveloper

i've a string like 'aabbcczx' and i need to split that string by 2 char.
The result expected is something like:

`aabbcczx  aa 
 aabbcczx  bb
 aabbcczx  cc
 aabbcczx  zx`

How can I do this?
consider also that the length of the string change row by row.

Thanks

Comment: If you really have a need for this, you might look to writing a proc or a function.

Comment: Is there a know length of the input string?

Answer (score 1):

If it's always 2 chars:

```
SELECT  A.Val,
        CA1.N,
        SUBSTRING(A.Val,n,2)
FROM    (
            VALUES ('aabbcczx')
        ) AS A(Val)
CROSS
APPLY   dbo.GetNums(1,LEN(A.Val)) AS CA1
WHERE   CA1.n % 2 = 1;
```

GetNums is a number table/tally table generator you can find some several sources online.

It will provide the position of each character and we can use that in the `substring` start position. The where clause uses `MOD` to so we only show every other starting position

Comment: +1 for posting better answer than the recursive answers. Those are coded to loop the text instead of the positions making them slow. They will also fail when the text is longer than 200 characters(easy to fix last part though)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), left(str, 2)) as val2, convert(varchar(max), stuff(str, 1, 2, '')) as rest, str
      from (values ( 'aabbcczx' )) v(str)
      union all
      select left(rest, 2) as val2, stuff(rest, 1, 2, '') as rest, str
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select str, val2
from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks, and if i need to create a string as below?

'aabbaa aa
aabbaa aabb
aabbaa aabbaa'

Comment: @Alvaro . . . Tis answers the question that you have asked.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query to extract pairs of characters:

```
with instring as 
 ( select 'aabbcczx' as s )
 , splitter as
 (
   select s, substring(s, 1, 2) as rslt, 3 as next -- first two chars
   from instring
   union all
   select s, substring(s, next, 2), next + 2       -- next two chars
   from splitter
   where len(s) >= next
 )
select *
from splitter
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b5c94d0add9a2e9c862f47ba52ea785a)